# have info from Facebook with swift?

Tags: xcode, facebook, email, swift

My code work for login with Facebook, but I can take the info, only the name e last name, I want the email and facebookid. How can I get that? Thanks

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, FBLoginViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet var fbLoginView : FBLoginView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.fbLoginView.delegate = self
    self.fbLoginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
}
@IBOutlet weak var etichetta: UILabel!

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func loginViewShowingLoggedInUser(loginView : FBLoginView!) {
    println("User Logged In")
    println("This is where you perform a segue.")
}

func loginViewFetchedUserInfo(loginView : FBLoginView!, user: FBGraphUser){ //subito dopo
    println("User birthday: \(user.birthday)")//not work is nil
    println("User name: \(user.name)")
    println("User username: \(user.objectID)")//not work is nil
}

func loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser(loginView : FBLoginView!) {
    println("User Logged Out")
}

func loginView(loginView : FBLoginView!, handleError:NSError) {
    println("Error: \(handleError.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fetch the email by making a request

```
func loginViewFetchedUserInfo(loginView : FBLoginView!, user: FBGraphUser) {

  FBRequestConnection.startForMeWithCompletionHandler { (connection, user, error) -> Void in
    if (error == nil){
      self.email = user.objectForKey("email") as String //declare a var email before
      self.userId= user.objectForKey("id") //declare a var userId before
    }
  }
}
```